# Literature recommendation on random graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, book-recommendation, random-graphs

I'm looking for introductory references on [random graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph) (commonly mentioned as Erdős–Rényi graphs), having previous acquaintance with basic graph theory. I know that Bela Bollobas' [book on random graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521797225) is **the** used reference, as are all his books really, but I find the book too terse for an introduction and not very accessible for non-experts of the field. If it helps, two books that I have very much enjoyed reading are, *[Introduction to graph theory by Trudeau](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486678709)* and *[A first Course in graph theory by Chartrand and Zhang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486483681)*, unfortunately none of them cover random graphs.

- Any suggestions, be they books, blogs or articles are welcome.

Comment: [Introduction to Random Graphs](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Random-Graphs-Alan-Frieze/dp/1107118506/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1443406186&sr=8-4&keywords=random+graphs) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think Random Graphs by Janson, Łuczak and Ruciński is also a good introduction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two nice introductions. First, as I mentioned in comments, it is

- [Introduction to Random Graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107118506), a recent book on the classical theory of random graphs, which presupposes much milder prerequisites than, e.g., Bollobas' classic. (The book is not sold yet, but you can find a draft on one of the authors' webpages)
- I also very much like the monumental (and freely available) work of Remco van der Hofstad [Lecture Notes Random Graphs and Complex Networks](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/). It goes well beyond Erdos-Renyi random graphs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm studying *random geometric graphs* (RGG's) in the context of ad-hoc wireless networks. I am not sure that I can help you but I will tell you what I know. Erdos-Renyi (or Bernoulli) random graphs are one example of a random graph but there are many others. Indeed, since the probability that a distinct pair of vertices share an edge is the same for all such pairs in the Erdos-Renyi graph, there is no spatial embedding of the vertices. This makes such graphs not so useful for the kind of things that I am interested in, where the probability that two vertices share an edge depends upon a random spatial embedding of the nodes (vertices), usually according to a spatial point process.

Anyway, if you are *only* interested in the Erdos-Renyi graph, do read their original paper - it is very accessible - called "On random graphs I".

If, alternatively, you think you may be interested in an overview of results primarily on the Gilbert graph and the $k$-nearest neighbour graph, then I can recommend "Random geometric graphs" in *Surveys in Combinatorics 2011*, authored by Mark Walters, as it provides both a very readable summary of some of the foundational results and simple proof techniques. It is **important** to note that both of these graph models involve a spatial embedding of the nodes in the plane, which you may not be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few books that have multiple sections about random graphs, such as:

- **Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis**, Michael Mitzenmacher and Eli Upfal (*I like this one*)
- Networks: An Introduction, Mark Newman
- Network Science, Albert-László Barabási